# Python: Load module by its name

Tags: python, django, import, module

I'm working on a django project that serves multiple sites; depending on the site I want to import different functionality from a different module; how do I import a module in Python if I have the name of its package and the module name itself as a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

in Python generally, you can use `__import__` builtin function or `imp` module features:

```
>>> sys1 = __import__("sys")
>>> import imp
>>> sys2 = imp.load_module("sys2", *imp.find_module("sys"))
>>> import sys
>>> sys is sys1 is sys2
True
```

Answer (score 8):

Django has its own import function to get an objet from a string. From [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.module_loading):

> ## `django.utils.module_loading`
>
> Functions for working with Python modules.
>
> ```
> import_string(dotted_path)
> ```
>
> Imports a dotted module path and returns the attribute/class designated by the last name in the path. Raises ImportError if the import failed. For example:
>
> ```
> from django.utils.module_loading import import_string
> ValidationError = import_string('django.core.exceptions.ValidationError')
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
> ```